# Агрегация данных

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется таблица:

```
data = {'id': [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2],
       'block': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b'],
       'a_score': [0.12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.81],
       'b_score': [0, 0.82, 0, 0.44, 0, 0],
       'c_score':[0, 0, 0.34, 0, 0.77, 0]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data
```

Необходимо сгруппировать данные следующим образом:

```
res = {'id': [1, 2],
       'a_score': [0.12, 0.81],
       'b_score': [0.44,  0.82],
       'c_score':[0.77, 0.34]}

res = pd.DataFrame(res)
res
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вы бы хоть что-то сами попытались. Это же элементарно:

```
res = data.groupby('id').sum() # .reset_index()
```